# Databinding from view to controller mvc razor

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to return from the main view some objects to the controller to be displayed in new view. The problem is returned object are always null.

In the main view I call javascript function :

```
var selected = function (dv, record, item, index, e) {
            var warnings = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
            window.open("/Examples/WarningDetail?wrng=" + JSON.stringify(warnings[index]), "_blank", "left=100,top=100,width=400,height=300,toolbar=1,resizable=0");
       };
```

In the controller I use this action:

```
public ActionResult WarningDetail(warning wrng)
        {
            return View(wrng);
        }
```

Note that warning is defined model in my application.

Comment: Are your warnings stored in a database? If so, you could pass in the ID of the warning and retrieve its details as implied in your `WarningDetail` action. If the serialized JSON string is too large, it could potentially get truncated by the Web browser since Web browsers have a limit on URL length. Probably not a good idea. I was having difficulty understanding your original question, but this is a suggestion that comes to mind.

Comment: @MarioJVargas warnings are the model of the current view
you are right about the URL lenght, i got the error and i dont now how to truncate the URL? whats the best idea to bind such data from view to controller

Comment: Can you update your post so it includes the code for the `warning` class? Another question, are your warnings read from a specific data source, such as Entity Framework or a Web service? The post needs additional details.